# Express Session doesn't unset variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using Node Express to develop the web application. In the new project I faced one simple issue but could not figure out the solution so looking for the help.

I used express-session to store the session data and stored some data in the session. After some function I set the session variable to null but still it calls the old session data while calling.

Below is my sample code to initialize session.

app.js

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'Hhueerutyier',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { secure: false }
}));
```

My Router

```
router.get('/',async function(req,res){
    if(req.session.count && req.session.count != null){
        req.session.count++;
    }else{
        req.session.count = 1;
    }
    let resData = res;
    //JSON.stringify.resData
    console.log("Before Reset =>",req.session.count);
    res.json({
        "data":"I am in check",
        "message" : req.session.msg,
        "count" : req.session.count,
      
    })

   
      req.session.msg = null;
      req.session.count = null; //setting the session varible to null
      console.log("After Reset",req.session.count);
    
})
```

gives output as

[image]

```
Expected Output
Before Reset => 1
After Reset => null
Before Reset => 1
After Reset => null
Before Reset => 1
After Reset => null
```

Comment: Did you try resetting the values before sending the res.json() response?

Comment: yeah when I reset the value before sending then it resets the variable, but that way we cannot send the data to the front end as before sending it will be set to null.

Comment: assign the count to a temporary variable such as let sessionCount = req.session.count so that you can send it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You must edit the session before sending the response!**

```js
const response = {
    "data":"I am in check",
    "message" : req.session.msg,
    "count" : req.session.count,
    
}

/// remove before sending response
req.session.msg = null;
req.session.count = null; 

// Send response
res.json(response)
```

You can also use `delete` statement to delete session item:

```js
delete req.session.msg;
delete req.session.count;
```

Finally, personally, I like using return statement when sending a response. It doesn't do anything technically, but it notices me that I shouldn't do anything after it.

```
return res.json(response)
```

Comment: Hi KiralLT, Thank you for the alternate solution. Yeah this can fix the problem, but I was wondering why it stopped working. More then 10 sites are still live and has no issue with the same pattern. :-)